# Is there any way to modify the basepath value at runtime in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have a scenario where I need to modify the basepath we are setting in

```
.value('app.config', {
   basePath: 'http://localhost:xxxx/'
})
```

According to the availability of internet connection , I need to change this value. What are the different ways to change this at runtime?